# Can`t load files for pygame project using pyqt resource system

Tags: python, pyqt, pygame

I have .qrc file:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="/data">
        <file alias="key.png">resources/blocks/key.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I generate resources_rc.py by pyrcc5, than in my main script:

```
import resources_rc.py
key = pygame.image.load(':/data/key.png').convert_alpha()
```

I get an error:

```
File "E:/Python game/main.py", line 137, in main
    key = pygame.image.load(':/data/key.png').convert_alpha()
pygame.error: Couldn't open :/data/key.png
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:/foo/bar` filenames are special filenames used by Qt's (and thus PyQt's) ressource system.

pygame is not PyQt- you won't be able to do that outside of Qt.